# Injecting a service in the RabbitMQ - ConfirmCallback class is not working

Tags: spring-rabbit

I have created a separate callback class implementing ConfirmCallback interface and overridden the confirm(). Corrlation data and ack is working fine. But I have injected using @Autowired a service to do some other activities after successful ack from the rabbitMQ. But that service reference is not injected at all. I have injected the same service in other classes it works fine. My code

```
public MyConfirmCallback implements ConfirmCallback {

@Autowired
private PostAckService postAckService;

public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, Boolean ack){
   //check the ack and verify the correlationdata.
   postAckService.clearData(....);
}

}
```

postAckService is throwing nullpointer exception. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

`MyConfirmCallback` has to be a bean in the application context for auto wiring to work. You can't simply use `new MyConfirmCallback()` in your application.

If you believe it's a bean, turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`; it emits lots of information about bean creation.